# TypeError: setCurrentWindow(): 1st arg can't be coerced to ij.gui.ImageWindow

Tags: jython, imagej

Hi I am a very novice when it comes to scripting. I am trying to write a Jython script that will take an image that is not at the front, in imageJ, and bring it to the front. I have tried using the WindowManager but routinely run into a similar error.

> TypeError: setCurrentWindow(): 1st arg can't be coerced to
>   ij.gui.ImageWindow

or some other form of this error. It seems as though activating an image that is not at the front shouldn't be too difficult.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
from ij import IJ
from ij import WindowManager as WM

titles = WM.getIDList()

WM.setCurrentWindow(titles[:1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WindowManager.setCurrentWindow` method takes an `ImageWindow` object, not an `int` image ID. But you can look up the `ImageWindow` for a given ID as follows:

```py
WM.getImage(imageID).getWindow()
```

Here is a working version of your code:

```py
from ij import IJ
from ij import WindowManager as WM

print("[BEFORE] Active image is: " + IJ.getImage().toString())

ids = WM.getIDList()
win = WM.getImage(ids[-1]).getWindow()
WM.setCurrentWindow(win)
win.toFront()

print("[AFTER] Active image is: " + IJ.getImage().toString())
```

#### Notes

- I renamed your `titles` variable to `ids` because the method `WindowManager.getIDList()` returns a list of `int` image IDs, *not* a list of `String` image titles.
- The `WM.getImage(int imageID)` method needs an `int`, not a list.  So I used `ids[-1]`, which is the last element of the `ids` list, not `ids[:1]`, which is a subarray. Of course, you could pass whichever image ID you wish.
- I added the call `win.toFront()`, which actually brings the window to the front. Calling `WM.setCurrentWindow(win)` is important in that it tells ImageJ that that image is now the active image... but it will not actually raise the window, which is what it seems like you want here.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to figure it out!